# Finding which Pythagorean triple has the smallest angle

Tags: c, algorithm

Information: `a` being the length of the shortest leg of a right triangle and `b` being the length of the other leg, the larger the difference between `a` and `b` the smaller the angle. That is:

- the triple (3, 4, 5) has a difference of 4-3=1
- the triple (5, 12, 13) has a difference of 12-5=7

Therefore the smallest angle would be in the triple (5, 12, 13)

I'm writing a program that compares all of the pythagorean triples defined in a range and prints the triple with the smallest angle.  What I have so far is not working and I have no idea where I can go from here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int smallest(int a, int b) {
  int difference = b - a;
  return 0;
}


int main() {

 int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, n, counter = 1, i = 0;

 printf("Please Enter a Positive Integer: \n");
 scanf("%d", &n);

 for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
   for (b = 0; b < c; b++) {
     for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
       if (a * a + b * b == c * c ) {
         printf("%d:\t%d %d %d\n", counter++, a, b, c);
       }
     }
   }
   i = counter - 1;
 }
 printf ("The difference is %d\n", smallest(a, b));
 printf ("There are %d Pythagorean Triples in this range.\n", i);
 return 0;
}
```

The program just prints the difference is 0

what I am looking for the program to print is, for the example above "The triangle with the smallest angle is (5, 12, 13)"

I know I have to sort the differences and compare them but this is all I have so far, any tips?

Comment: You're off to a good start. Now you need to calculate the difference between the two legs of the current triangle and find out if it's smaller than the "best" triangle you've seen so far. If it is, you'll need to save the difference so you can compare it against the next triangle, and you'll also need to save the lengths of the sides so you can print them when you're done.

Comment: what do you mean by "save" as i am very new to C and dont know much terminology, how do i compare the values, i can do it with an array but im not sure how to do it with integer values such as the values of c, b, a

Comment: When the code prints `a`, `b`, and `c`, it's identified a pythagorean triple. Now you need to calculate the difference between `a` and `b`. If it's the largest difference you've seen so far, store it in another variable, say `largest`, so you can compare the next `b-a` to it.

Comment: What i dont understand is how can i compare the next b-a when all of the variables are declared as c, b, a

Comment: You're the programmer. You get to declare as many variables as you need.  :-)  It's fine to declare another `int` at the top.

Comment: okay but how can i declare this int variable to a specific triple? :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39782/discussion-between-adam-liss-and-ptrickono)

Comment: "the larger the difference between a and b the smaller the angle" ― this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure your 'information' is right? Because triple (30, 40, 50) has a difference of 10 and just the same angle as (3, 4, 5).
2. You don't have to sort, you have to remember difference/angle/whatever you minimize, as already mentioned in comments. Also, you have to remember values of 'minimal' (a,b,c) to print them later. Something like this:

   ```
   //...
   if (a * a + b * b == c * c ) {
     printf("%d:\t%d %d %d\n", counter++, a, b, c); //if you use ++counter instead, you won't need i ;)
     if(minDifference < b-a){ //Don't be afraid of variables with long names
       minA = a; minB = b; minC = c; minDifference = b-a;
     }
   }
   //...
   printf("The triangle with the smallest difference is (%d, %d, %d)", minA, minB, minC);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your `smallest`-code returns 0 in every case. Are you sure you don't want to return `difference` instead (or even `b-a`)?

```
int smallest(int a, int b) {
  return b-a;
}
```